# How can i upload an .docx file to my GoogleDrive with Python?

Tags: python, file-upload, scripting, google-drive-api

I wrote a simple script to upload a .docx file to my GoogleDrive Account. It works perfectly, except for the file.. Authentication works, uploading the file works. I had some trouble with encoding, but now with Latin-1 I can upload the file without any errors. But after the upload, there is only an Untitled Document with this content:

[Content_Types].xml  l"%3 ^i7+ %p)O 5}nH" t4Q+ |T\y _rels/.rels  jH[{     l0/% word/_rels/document.xml.rels  }-;}PB `[^^l :>S!?p (!O>z word/document.xml )Zb#~J K{N$ 7R'~/ $]t# V-wZ TMco %NPB5 ~e!(m zJSC aPdO4 Jr#Cv l%|Y AxQT;K3[ word/theme/theme1.xml p{{<F! :@q" ?~|f hNC- 055B jf;a ssFb dZ#QZn: ]{,n t}Vz}1 !(~X "(<Ik^> o[HD kW:A word/settings.xml rZiidm &sY5 \w'5>X ^JL\ I'I6 9FVM  v8:y- o9E1G "ogH:`:nM word/fontTable.xml WkU+ PlQ(! IX(* +>_ze|PXPD OJK ?eK #83> word/webSettings.xml Bk"15i I?`| RjRlq docProps/app.xml  X2<$ I3S.u docProps/core.xml  P`nQ d\l2 ) C5 $Tehk J06t `UUA5iQ 10Tse >yx\-P word/styles.xml IPL0 U&dz2 5&{K 5IwM ,x9fY( fMNF< {2bjkrj G!vMD -TA{ ~TAG 0Epr 9F{7w x0-d x^(G ynL" fl9g2z Z{Jtx [z^| Q)aaT2X )aD[ qfaT z#B^  -iwJ x_}[ I]Qx3 eTHA cTHA py}) t /5DyK hnB_ )5.[ %5.[ /5.[ eKmR )5.[ CfmmV RyxS%u u}nY xegY'` &m]n [Content_Types].xmlPK _rels/.relsPK word/_rels/document.xml.relsPK word/document.xmlPK word/theme/theme1.xmlPK word/settings.xmlPK word/fontTable.xmlPK word/webSettings.xmlPK RjRlq docProps/app.xmlPK docProps/core.xmlPK word/styles.xmlPK

How can I make the script handle the .docx format? I read that .docx files are actually zipfiles, is this true?

And another Question:
How can I upload the file in a specific GoogleDrive folder? Do I have to specify this in my GoogleDrive-API Project?

Thanks in advance :)

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
import os

g_login = GoogleAuth()
g_login.LocalWebserverAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(g_login)

test = "Path to my BA_UploadTest.docx"
with open(test, "r", encoding="Latin-1")as file:
  fn = os.path.basename(file.name)
  file_drive = drive.CreateFile({'BA_UploadTest.docx':     os.path.basename(file.name)})
file_drive.SetContentString(file.read())
file_drive.Upload()
print('File upload successful!')
```

Comment: "I had some trouble with encoding, but now with Latin-1 I can upload the file without any errors" - Not really, looking at your result. Print the `file.read()` before uploading to see what you're really sending. Also, the code you posted has broken indentation, `file.read` in the posted code is outside `with`.

Comment: Also, have you tried any other file, like a simple text file? It can be that SetContentString really just sets content of a *text* file, and type of the file is set elsewhere.

Comment: Dont look at the formatting pls :D I just didnt copied the code right. But you are right, file.read() is None. I tried it with a simple txt file. Its also uploaded as Untitled, but the Content is right

Comment: So SetContentString didnt work for a txt file as well

Comment: Oh, sorry, if you do `file.read()`, you need to save its contents because it can go through the file twice. My mistake. | BUT: As I said, it sets the file *content* and google drive doesn't look at the extension. You need to find how to set file type.

Answer (score 1):

By using the Python Quickstart code provided in the [Google Drive API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python), you can upload files to Google Drive by specifying the MIME Type of the file in the request rather than relying on the default of `None` as specified in the [`MediaFileUpload` class](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.http.MediaFileUpload-class.html).

[The MIME Type for `.docx` files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types) is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` and so this can be set as such. Using the below code, I was able to upload `.docx` files to my Google Drive without any encoding or readability issues:

```
import authentication
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

#...

def docxDriveUpload(service):

    file_metadata = {'name': 'demo.docx'}
    media = MediaFileUpload('demo.docx', mimetype='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')

    file = service.files().create(body = file_metadata, media_body = media, fields = 'id').execute()

    print 'File upload successful! File ID: %s' % file.get('id')
```

In order to upload a file to a specific folder in your Drive, you need to use the unique Folder ID in the upload query. You can get this by visiting `drive.google.com`, opening the folder in browser view, and copying the string after /folders/ in the URL.
`https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

Comment: Thanks for your help! What exactly is that "service" attribute in your function?

Comment: `service` is the built connection to the API service, in this case to the Drive REST API. Check out the Quickstart documentation for sample code to authenticate and use the service https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python